# Is zero absolute limit equivalent to zero limit?

Tags: limits

Is is true that:

$\lim$ $|a_n| = 0$ $\equiv \lim$ $a_n = 0$

I know that

$\lim$ $|a_n| = 0$ $\leftarrow \lim$ $a_n = 0$.

But what about the other direction?

Thanks very much

Comment: Notice that $-|a_n|\leq a_n \leq |a_n|$. The Squeeze Theorem does the job.

Comment: @ThongNguyenThanh Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use the squeeze (or sandwich) theorem

Suppose $\lim a_n=0$ then $\lim -a_n=0$ by the constant multiple rule and for each $n$ we have one of the following two inequalities

$$
-a_n \le |a_n|  \le a_n
$$

or

$$
a_n \le |a_n|  \le -a_n
$$

so by the squeeze theorem $\lim a_n=0$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $|a_n|\to 0$. Then given $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such  that $n> N$ implies that
$$
|a_n-0|=||a_n|-0|<\epsilon
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$-|a_n|\le a_n \le |a_n|$$

then by squeeze theorem we can conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n| = 0 \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes on the question in the title.

The following statements are equivalent because $||a_n|-0|=||a_n||=|a_n|=|a_n-0|$

- $\forall\epsilon>0\exists n\in\mathbb N\forall k>n \left[||a_n|-0|\leq\epsilon\right]$
- $\forall\epsilon>0\exists n\in\mathbb N\forall k>n\left[|a_n-0|\leq\epsilon\right]$